# "вы" или "Вы"

Tags: прописная-строчная, местоимение

Какую форму следует предпочесть при обращении к одному интервьюируемому (интервью напечатано в газете)?

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, было бы гораздо проще, если бы единственным критерием написания со строчной или прописной было число (множественное или единственное): обращение к одному человеку (или к каждому по отдельности) - "Вы", к группе людей - "вы". Критерий вежливости не выдерживает никакой критики. Есть мнение, что называть человека на "вы" - само по себе уже вежливо, большая буква не обязательна. Но тогда в "шкале вежливости" будет уже три звена: ты-вы-Вы. Как же тогда объяснить написание "вы": средне-вежливо? Лучше вообще исключить такой критерий. Вспоминается это правило: "При обращении к одному лицу (физическому или юридическому) в официальных документах и личных письмах местоимения Вы и Ваш пишутся с прописной буквы как форма выражения *вежливости*: Сообщаем Вам...". Что же тогда, в остальных случаях можно быть "не очень вежливым"?    
И в интервью я бы писала "Вы" с заглавной (обращение к одному человеку).

Answer (score 2):

> На самом деле «вы» пишется с большой
> буквы только при обращении к одному
> лицу и **только** в текстах определенных
> жанров: *личные письма*, *официальные
> документы* (например, служебные
> записки). И еще один случай написания
> «вы» с большой буквы — это *тексты,
> предназначенные для многократного
> использования*: анкеты, листовки.

Это цитата из [интервью](http://mn.ru/society_edu/20130128/336414075.html) "Московским новостям" главного редактора портала "Грамота.ру" Владимра Пахомова. О том же самом, со ссылками на словари, говорится и на самом [портале](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_88).

Интервью - не официальный документ, не личное письмо и в данном случае, по видимому, не анкета. Соответственно "вы" должно печататься со строчной буквы.

В общем, "вы" с заглавной буквы, вне официальных бумаг, означает крайнюю степень уважения собеседника. В устной речи заглавная буква выражалась бы восторженной либо подобострастной интонацией. Если вы собеседника уважаете без восхищения им, т.е. в 99% случаев, "вы" со строчной буквы будет достаточно и в личном письме.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь столько споров было по этому поводу...
Но в данном случае, если я правильно понял ситуацию, то, пожалуй, с заглавной: Вы.

ЗЫ Интервью бралось в устной форме, но предполагало печатный вид? Я воспринимаю это скорее как письменнное общение с одним лицом. Хотя можно спорить...

Answer (score 1):

Нет, со строчной. Я сделала сотни интервью в своей жизни и всегда писала со строчной. Ведь обращение тут не к читателю, а к интервьюируемому.

Comment: Мы одинаково понимаем ситуацию? Обращение к интервьюируемому вы сичтаете устным?

Comment: А можно поподробнее? В моем интервью была масса вопросов с "Вы" (к одному интервьюируемому), везде исправили на "вы". Посмотрела чужие интервью, во всех - "вы".  
Это как-то связано с читаемостью? Прописная буква отвлекает внимание? Или есть еще какое-то объяснение?  

На сайте Грамота.ру рекомендуют к одному лицу обращаться "Вы". http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_88

Еще употребление прописной буквы может быть смыслоразличительным. Например, если берется интервью у нескольких лиц одновременно, а вопросы перемежаются (лично к кому-то или ко всем сразу).

Comment: А что тут "подробнее"? При передаче на письме устной речи "Вы" обычно не используют. Возможно потому, что в устной речи его передать невозможно. Это даже не правило, скорее - традиция, но весьма, имхо разумная, освобождающая текст от излишнего официоза. Но это еще и от редактора зависит, в каждом заведении - свои причуды.   
Что касается мнения грамоты, то оно неоднократно обсасывалось со всех сторон, общего мнения нет, но в общем-то с тем, что ответ неоднозначный/неполный, обычно соглашаются.
Смыслоразличитаельная функция тут побоку. Обходятся же англичане своим you/your.

Comment: Я уточняю, а то получился некий диссонанс с моим основным ответом.
Сказанное тут относилось к интервью устному, для которое бумага - только способ передачи. Но это не исключает "Вы" с заглавной в интервью устном лишь по форме, о чем я говорил в основном ответе.  
Хотя, признаться, за последнее время я потерял былую уверенность в своем однозначном и исчерпывающем понимании всей проблемы.

Comment: Я вот тоже сомневаюсь. В поздравлениях дорогим и уважаемым взрослым я пишу "Вы", но там же я могу и "с днем рождения" с большой буквы написать, чтобы подчеркнуть значимость события ( это ж не для всех).   
  С интервью сложнее. Ведь устное - это тоже по сути письменное, его ж не пересказываешь, а пишешь/печатаешь.

Answer (score 1):

Считаю любые дополнения к ссылке излишними:
http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/165/#02

Comment: Считаю излишним напоминать, что Артемий Великий не является авторитетным источником в данной области.  
Хотя мнение его давно известно и принято к сведенью.

Comment: А я все равно буду писать Вы, и Артемий мне не указ. Впрочем, и все остальные тоже.