# Как писать "вы" при обращении, со строчной или прописной?

Tags: стилистика, прописная-строчная

В каких случаях нужно писать "вы" со строчной буквы и в каких — с прописной?
Меня упрекают на некоторых форумах, что, обращаясь к незнакомому человеку, я пишу слово "вы" со строчной буквы, то бишь с маленькой.

Comment: Неплохая информация есть здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/вы-или-Вы и здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/83/Вы-с-большой-или-с-маленькой. Прежде чем задать вопрос, просматривайте "Поиск по сайту..." — там достаточно квалифицированных ответов.

Answer (score 0):

С большой буквы пишут только в письменных обращениях к одному лицу, например, в *переписке* или в *анкете*, которую предлагается заполнить. В форуме же (исключая личную почту) переписка публична, и это аналог устной беседы, поэтому обращение с большой буквы не принято (как и в записи устных диалогов в литературе и титрах к фильмам). Претензии к вам безосновательны.

Comment: Читая письма Пушкина. я не раз видел, что часто он писал также "вы" с маленькой буквы. (К Тургеневу, Плетнёву и проч.) И даже в письме к императору Александру он пишет, хоть и на французском языке, но тоже со строчной - ваше величество, прошу вашего соизволения... А как в этом случае?

Comment: Спасибо за предыдущий ответ! Значит, моя совесть чиста. )

Comment: Вероятно, вариант написания с большой буквы появился ещё позже, чем обращение на "вы" к одному лицу. Вот сравнительно подробный материал по теме: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/51-rubric-88